# How to create html buttons with checkboxes with Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a table with 4 checkboxes. Lets say with Title,Adress,Postal Code and Email.

```
<table class="mytable">
         <tbody>
         <tr>
         <td> <input type="checkbox" value="title"> title </td>
        <td> <input type="checkbox" value="adress">  Adress </td>
        <td> <input type="checkbox" value="postalcode">  Postal Code </td>
        <td> <input type="checkbox" value="email">  Email </td>
         </tr>
</table>
```

I have another div with class "myfilters" which is hidden when none of the above checkboxes are checked.

```
<div class="myfilters">
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm"> Title </button>

 <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm"> Adress</button>       
</div>
```

My question is How can I implement **when a user checks lets say "title" and "adress" checkboxes** in the table
**then inside the div "myfilters" to be created dynamically the buttons "Title" and the Button "Address**" ?

Comment: do you want to add button title after checking the checkbox title?

Comment: you can use .append() http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_dom_add.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this :

```
$(function(){
  $('.mytable').on("change","input[type=checkbox]",function(){
      if($(this).is(':checked'))
      {
        var button = '<button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" id="'+$(this).val()+'">'+$(this).parent().text()+'</button>';
        $('.myfilters').append(button);
      }
      else
      {
         $('.myfilters').find('button[id="'+$(this).val()+'"]').remove();
      }
  });
});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/79wdswL7/6/)**

Answer (score 3):

Don't add the buttons dynamically. Create them in the HTML, but hide them with CSS. Then show them when you click on the corresponding checkbox.

```js
$(":checkbox").click(function() {
  $("#"+this.value).toggle(this.checked);
});
```

```css
.btn {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="mytable">
         <tbody>
         <tr>
         <td> <input type="checkbox" value="title"> title </td>
        <td> <input type="checkbox" value="adress">  Adress </td>
        <td> <input type="checkbox" value="postalcode">  Postal Code </td>
        <td> <input type="checkbox" value="email">  Email </td>
         </tr>
</table>

<div class="myfilters">
 <button type="button" id="title" class="btn btn-default btn-sm"> Title </button>

 <button type="button" id="adress" class="btn btn-default btn-sm"> Adress</button>   
  <button type="button" id="postalcode" class="btn btn-default btn-sm"> Postal Code</button>  
  <button type="button" id="email" class="btn btn-default btn-sm"> Email</button>  
</div>
```

Comment: +1, This solution will run faster than js scripts that are creating and appending html to the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

This is what you need (notice that I've added the IDs for checkboxes):

```
<table class="mytable">
  <tr>
    <td><input id="c1" type="checkbox" value="title">Title</td>
    <td><input id="c2" type="checkbox" value="adress">Address</td>
    <td><input id="c3" type="checkbox" value="postalcode">Postal Code</td>
    <td><input id="c4" type="checkbox" value="email">Email</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#c1").click(function(){
    $(".myfilers").append("<button>Title</button>");
  });

  $("#c2").click(function(){
    $(".myfilers").append("<button>Address</button>");
  });

  $("#c3").click(function(){
    $(".myfilers").append("<button>Postal Code</button>");
  });

  $("#c4").click(function(){
    $(".myfilers").append("<button>Email</button>");
  });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a fiddle Demo,  [FIDDLE DEMO CLICK HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/Faizan_Alam/Lw7q7pu4/3/)

```
 var myNull=null; // ignore this line
```